# Deployer.org - Recipe changes are not being applied on Magento deploying

Tags: magento2, deploy, deployment

I'm using [this recipe](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/magento2.php) to deploy Magento 2 with [Deployer.org](https://deployer.org).

It's not getting my changes.

For example the writable_dirs are set this wait:

```
set('writable_dirs', [
    'var',
    'pub/static',
    'pub/media',
    'generated'
]);
```

All those folder are being created with no content, no images.

Also, I tried to add a new task to restart PHP-FPM after deployment:

```
task('reload:php-fpm', function () {
    run('sudo /usr/sbin/service php7-fpm reload');
});

after('deploy', 'reload:php-fpm');
```

Even defining the most simple custom task:

```
task('test', function () {
    writeln('Hello world');
});
```

Nothing happening. Deployer is not taking any custom changes.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my `documentRoot` at Apache like:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/magento/folder/current/
```

(This is neccesary according to the [official documentation](https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started.html))

So, recipes are being deployed and read from:

```
/path/to/magento/folder/releases/XX/recipe
```

Not from:

```
/path/to/magento/folder/recipe/
```

There are two solutions:

- Customize the recipes located into releases folder (Not recommended)
- Add your custom changes to `/path/to/magento/folder/deployer.php`. This way, we can be sure your deployment will be executed properly no matter what happen with your releases folder.